# Unable To Use ch.qos.logback.classic Classes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, logback

I have spring project setup on Intellij Idea 2016.2 using Maven. For some reason I cannot import or use any class present in `ch.qos.logback.classic` package. I tried to invalidate cache, re-import maven dependencies.

For example with

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
```

the IDE says 'cannot resolve symbol Level'. When compiling from command line it says 'package ch.qos.logback.classic does not exist'. Any suggestion what might be wrong?

**Update -** found the issue. I had set dependency scope to compile. Updating this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` Maven artifact in your dependencies?

You should have something like that in your pom :

```
<dependencies>
     ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
     ...
<dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the issue and updated the question.

Comment: I had set dependency scope to compile. Updating this fixed the issue.

Comment: by default, `compile` scope  is used. That means that you had precised another scope I suppose. Right ?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue after updating to the newest version of Eclipse (for some reason), the scope was set to "runtime" and by just deleting the <scope> tag entirely it solved the problem for me.