# Package doesnot exist on maven compilation

Tags: java, maven

There exist a class in project that uses ILoggingEvent which is found to be imported from logback-classic.jar. It is available in project as maven dependency as well and in .m2 folder. But when i do mvn clean install, I get below error:

> [ERROR] /C:/Users/xxx/project/LogMonitor.java:[6,34] package
>
> ch.qos.logback.classic.spi does not exist
>
> cannot find symbol symbol:
>   class ILoggingEvent

When i extracted files from jar,I was able to find the same package with that jar. Above all , i see no error mark in LogMonitor class too , though it is the one which uses ILoggingEvent
I tried maven update,project clean. But still i see it failing. There is no issue in configuration of maven as another repository is built successful. Please favour on how it can be resolved

Edit:
pom file of repo where this code exist.:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-pom</artifactId>
        <version>0.25.5</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>aws</artifactId>


pom of common:
 <groupId>com.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>common-pom</artifactId>
  <version>0.25.5</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>Common</name>
  <modules>
    <module>xxx</module>
  </modules>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependencies>
   <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Comment: Post your POM file.

Comment: May be this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076734/unable-to-use-ch-qos-logback-classic-classes

Comment: @Gimhani  As i said, eclipse showed no error that such a class is not found . that's what puzzled me

Comment: @chrylis added as you asked for.

Comment: @Gayathri Try it with a specified version for logback-classic.jar.

Comment: that's available in common's parent. with version 1.2.3

Comment: show the dependency management section for logback-classic.jar.  Is the scope  just test?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is bad practice to have actual dependencies in a parent pom. Instead you should only have the dependency-management in the parent pom to specify the versions of the dependencies that should be used and then in the consuming children the required dependencies. Otherwise you might end-up with jars on the classpaths of projects that do not actually require them.

In short:
The parent pom (you common pom) should only contain:

```
 <groupId>com.common</groupId>
 <artifactId>common-pom</artifactId>
 <version>0.25.5</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>Common</name>
 <modules>
   <module>xxx</module>
 </modules>
 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
       <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.3</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
       <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.3</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 <dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

And the consumers of the parent pom will then contain the dependencies without the version number:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

The important part is that you specify the correct version number and the designated scope at some point(see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Answer (score -1):

Your dependency should look like this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The scope is maybe set to `<scope>test</scope>` . If you want to use it in `src/main/java`, you have to set the scope at compile (default when no scope is defined)